# 'imagecolorat' and transparency

Tags: php, image, transparency, pixel

How it's possible to get the **transparency** value of a pixel on an **image**?

'imagecolorat' picks only the index of the color of the pixel at the specified location in the image. With that index I can get the RGB values but not the transparent one.

Hope you understand, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, the transparency value is returned by the function `imagecolorat`. Could you try:

```
$color        = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
$transparency = ($color >> 24) & 0x7F;
```

The transparency is a integer between 0 and 127 so we need to mask the first 8 bits of the 32bit color integer.

Comment: Oh, thanks!

I didn't know that imagecolorat, in fact, contains the alpha value.

Comment: Note the 4th byte is for transparency, not opacity. Thus `0` means fully opaque and `127` means fully transparent. In other environments this might be reversed, for example in css, where `0.0` is fully transparent and `1.0` is fully opaque.

Comment: How large is a 32-bit value? Because `imagecolorat` is returning 16777215.

Answer (score 14):

the solution could be following:

```
$colorIndex = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y);
$colorInfo = imagecolorsforindex($img, $colorIndex);
print_r($colorInfo);
```

that will print something like:

```
Array
(
   [red] => 226
   [green] => 222
   [blue] => 252
   [alpha] => 0
)
```

where [alpha] is Your transparency value... (from 0 to 127 where 0 is totaly opaque and 127 is totaly transparent)

Enjoy!

Comment: hmmm i thought alpha value is from 0 to 255 , 0 mean transparent and 255 mean no transparent

Answer (score 1):

According to the PHP manual imagecolorat returns the index of the colour at the specified X/Y coordinates (i'm assuming this is for GIF and/or PNG-8).

If you know the index, then the problem is determining which index in the file is the transparent one.

imagecolortransparent might be worth looking at, imagecolorsforindex may also be helpful.