# PHP imageconvolution() leaves black dot in the upper left corner

Tags: php, transparent, image-resizing, php-gd

I'm trying to sharpen resized images using this code:

```
imageconvolution($imageResource, array(
        array( -1, -1, -1 ),
        array( -1, 16, -1 ),
        array( -1, -1, -1 ),
    ), 8, 0);
```

When the transparent PNG image is sharpened, using code above, it appears with a black dot in the upper left corner (I have tried different convolution kernels, but the result is the same). After resizing the image looked OK.

1st image is the original one

2nd image is the sharpened one

[image: Original image]
[image: Sharpen image]

**EDIT**: What am I going wrong? I'm using the color retrieved from pixel.

```
$color = imagecolorat($imageResource, 0, 0);
    imageconvolution($imageResource, array(
        array( -1, -1, -1 ),
        array( -1, 16, -1 ),
        array( -1, -1, -1 ),
    ), 8, 0);
            imagesetpixel($imageResource, 0, 0, $color);
```

Is `imagecolorat` the right function? Or is the position correct?

**EDIT2**: I have changed coordinates, but still no luck. I've check the transparency given by `imagecolorat` (according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702953/imagecolorat-and-transparency)). This is the dump:

```
array(4) {
   red => 0
   green => 0
   blue => 0
   alpha => 127
}
```

Alpha 127 = 100% transparent. Those zeroes might cause the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the convolution code (corners are special cases in some implementations).

As a workaround, you can save the pixel value in that corner just before the convolution and restore it afterwards, with `imageSetPixel()`.

The pixel you need to save is at (0,0), and possibly you will need to also check the transparency (but I think it should work with just `imageColorAt` and `imageSetPixel`).

**TEST CODE**

The file 'giants.png' I wgot from the one you posted above. If I do not use `imageSetPixel` I experience the same extra pixel you got. With `imageSetPixel`, the image looks correct to me.

Possibly there's some slight difference in the sequence I run `ImageSaveAlpha` or set alpha blending.

```
<?php
        $giants = ImageCreateFromPNG('giants.png');

        $imageResource = ImageCreateTrueColor(190, 190);

        ImageColorTransparent($imageResource, ImageColorAllocateAlpha($imageResource, 0, 0, 0, 127));
        ImageAlphaBlending($imageResource, False);
        ImageSaveAlpha($imageResource, True);

        ImageCopyResampled($imageResource, $giants, 0, 0, 0, 0, 190, 190, ImageSX($giants), ImageSY($giants));

        $color = ImageColorAt($imageResource, 0, 0);
        ImageConvolution($imageResource, array(
                        array( -1, -1, -1 ),
                        array( -1, 16, -1 ),
                        array( -1, -1, -1 ),
                ), 8, 0);
        ImageSetPixel($imageResource, 0, 0, $color);
        ImagePNG($imageResource, 'dwarves.png');
?>
```

Comment: I have tried it, but no success...can you please check my edit?

Comment: I have made changes but without succcess