# Making image sharp with imagefilter() in php

Tags: php, image, image-processing, fonts, gd

Is there any possibilities to make image more sharp using `imagefilter()` function? I am using `imagettftext()` which adds Anti-aliasing to fonts and the fonts looks bit de-focused. I like to make my final image bit sharpen so that I can reduce the blur around the char's in my image.

### Different Test Images

- **Font used**

  - Roboto-Thin.ttf
  - Roboto-Black.ttf

#### Image with light fonts

I like to have my fonts to look something like those lines next to it.

[image]

#### Image with dark fonts

[image]

#### Image with -$font_color (Some web resources suggested to make font colour value to negative which basically turns off the anti-aliasing) But in this case the fonts looks ugly. (Left-To-Right 100 is with turned off anti-aliasing)

[image]

Comment: I think you could achieve that by using `IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST`. Since that would make the black colors darker. For more about it, check here http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GD Solution**

```
$old = "old.png";
$new = "new.png";

$im = imagecreatefrompng($imgname);
imagetruecolortopalette($im, FALSE, 256);
imagecolorset($im, imagecolorclosest($im, 159, 159, 159), 0, 0, 0);
imagecolorset($im, imagecolorclosest($im, 191, 191, 191), 0, 0, 0);

imagepng($im, $new);
imagedestroy($im);
```

**Image Magic Solution**

```
convert old.png -fuzz 0% -fill rgb(0,0,0) -opaque rgb(159,159,159) new.png
convert new.png -fuzz 0% -fill rgb(0,0,0) -opaque rgb(191,191,191) new.png
```

**They would output**

[image]  [image]

```
                  Old                           new
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no such filter *in imagefilter()* (you did try `IMG_FILTER_EDGEDETECT`? For sharp transitions maybe it can get you something). But you can try and use `imageconvolution` instead:

```
imageconvolution($imageResource, array(
    array( -1, -1, -1 ),
    array( -1, 16, -1 ),
    array( -1, -1, -1 ),
), 8, 0);
```

You may want to look at [PHP imageconvolution() leaves black dot in the upper left corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918060/php-imageconvolution-leaves-black-dot-in-the-upper-left-corner) , there appeared to be an issue with `imageconvolution`

Another possibility is to resize the image before applying text, making it (say) 200% larger. Then apply the text using a font again 200% larger. Then downsample the image. Depending on font characteristics, this will have the effect of reducing the blur. Using integer powers of 2 (200%, 400%, ...) helps reducing artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the two extremes of the Roboto font. Pick the light or Regular version and it will be dark without being *too* dark.

The anti-aliasing function of the font renderer can't make the thin lines less than one pixel thick, so it makes them dim instead.